# How to translate .htaccess to webconfig ASP MVC

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My Website unfortunately cloned, I don't know how or what i can do to stop them ..

So i tried many ways but nothing work .. they seems like can get access to db or something .

Anyway i found someone saying that this code in htaccess stopped the problem but i don't know how to translate this to .Net Webconfig ..

```
# Whitelist domain
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^(www\.)?yourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

So if someone can help me with translating this and if someone **has experience with stopping this sites from keep cloning my site** i appreciate this .

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIS Url Rewrite extension to import or convert htaccess file rules into .NET compatible url rewrite rules.

I converted the provided htaccess rules which resulted in the following:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <!--# Whitelist domain-->
        <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="^(www\.)?yourdomain\.com$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks for translating it .. It's not works for me , but there is no error ... the clone sites still on and there is no redirect or 403 when you load they sites